# String concatenation with variables and pointers in 'C'

Tags: c, string, string-concatenation, cs50, strcat

I am working on Caesar's cipher for an online course and I have a problem with the original value being in the final output, and I cannot seem to get rid of it. My suspicion is that it is due to

```
strcpy(str1, &final_val);
strcat(str2, str1);
```

being called in a wrong way, so when I run

```
make test && ./test 1
```

This provides my program with the argument `1` and provides the key to shift the letters and encode the message. I expect to see

```
plaintext: asd
ciphertext: bcd
```

Instead I get

```
plaintext: asd
ciphertext: bacbdc
```

If you want to try out the code, you will need to do it inside of [this sanbox](https://sandbox.cs50.io/d832becd-852d-459a-88ed-a9c3cdcc792e), because it has the required CS50 library.

**Code**

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

bool input_valid(int count, string arg);
bool in_alphabet(int count, string arg);

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    int key;
    int ascii_val;
    char final_val;
    string string;

    char str1[80];
    char str2[80];

    // check input again if validation fails
    if (!input_valid(argc, argv[1])) {
        printf("Invalid input!\nUSAGE: ./caesar key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string = get_string("plaintext: ");

    // get integer from string input
    key = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        ascii_val = (int)string[i];

        bool valid_lower_case = (ascii_val + key) >= 97 && (ascii_val + key) <= 122;
        bool valid_upper_case = (ascii_val + key) >= 65 && (ascii_val + key) <= 90;

        // check if value is a letter
        if (isalpha(string[i])) {
            // check if value is in the valid alphabet range
            if (valid_lower_case || valid_upper_case) {
                final_val = ascii_val + key;
            } else {
                // for lowercase: wrap around if the letter passes 'z'
                final_val = 97 + (key - (122 - (ascii_val - 1)));
            }
        } else {
            final_val = ascii_val;
        }

        strcpy(str1, &final_val);
        strcat(str2, str1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", str2[i]);
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", str2);
}

bool input_valid(int count, string arg) {
    // input has more args than just the file name
    // input is an integer
    return count > 1 && isdigit(arg[0]);
}
```

Comment: 1. `strcpy` take *C strings* (NUL-terminated strings) as arguments; you can't just pass an arbitrary `char*`.  2. `str2` is never initialized, so `strcat(str2, ...)` is appending to garbage.

Comment: `str2` is initialized on line 17 with `char str2[80];`

Comment: No it isn't.  That *declares* `str2`.  As a local variable, it's not initialized to anything.

Comment: Would it help to `char str2[80] = {0};`

Comment: Yes, that would fix the initialization problem.

Answer (score 2):

`strcpy(str1, &final_val);` is undefined behavior. `strcpy` expects both parameters to be pointers to null-terminated strings. However, since arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions, `strcpy` doesn't know the difference between a pointer to an array of characters and the address of a single `char` variable.

It will try to copy memory beginning at `&final_val` into `str1`, only stopping when it encounters a null terminator elsewhere in your process' memory, if there is one. To copy a single character to a string, just use `str[x] = ch` and `str[x + 1] = '\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

Replaced `strcopy()` and `strcat()`. Got it to work by appending to `str2` like this:

```
str2[i] = final_val;
```